# ClassNotFoundException error in apache karaf

Tags: apache-karaf, aries

I added `contect-param` tab in the `web.xml` file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>blueprintLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

also `listner` class in the `web.xml` file

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.aries.blueprint.web.BlueprintContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

after loading to karaf, I am getting the error below:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.aries.blueprint.web.BlueprintContextListener not found by com.test.test.core.jsonstore-http-api

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that your bundle is probably not importing the package **org.apache.aries.blueprint.web** at his MANIFEST.MF file.

There are several ways to fix that, if you are using [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html), you can add the package manually to the **Import-Package** directive, just like this:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Import-Package>
        org.apache.aries.blueprint.web,
        *
        </Import-Package>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

If you are using another tool to generate your manifest, it should be similar to that.

Comment: Just to explain why this happens... Normally the maven-bundle-plugin finds the packages you need by scanning your classes and their imports. In this case the dependency is only in a blueprint file. So it is not found by the automatic scanning.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i added the org.apache.aries.blueprint.web in the import package tag in the pom.xml in the same as you mentioned, but still the error exists. When i copied the bundle's war file and pasted to deploy folder of karaf, that error has gone. Is there any otherway to resolve it ?

Comment: also my main goal is to inject bundles in the servlet application using aries blueprint which is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930549/how-to-inject-apache-karaf-bundles-as-a-service-in-the-web-application-using-ari, can you please help on this?